# C# : Returning how many coins of what kind should be returned

Tags: c#

What algorithm can be used to determine how many of each coins (2 , 1 , 0.5 , 0.2 , 0.1 and 0.05) are necessary to reflect a total monetary value (rounded to the smallest coin unit if necessary)?

Bigger coins should have highest priority.

E.g.

```
2.55$ = 1x2 + 1x0.5 + 1x0.05
```

Comment: This shouldn't be closed and is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @plalx that's kinda questionable; if they had an idea but were struggling with a specific part of the implementation, sure. But as it is, this is just "do my homework for me". The OP has demonstrated no attempt to even start.

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried to rephrase the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @plalx it still isn't a coding question :) and in terms of algorithms: since the question states to prioritise larger coins, there is no algorithmic dilecision to be made: there is exactly one algorithm that can be used. All that is left is: to write it. Hence how this is just "do my homework"

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the edit, and indeed this is in my opinion a valid question?

Comment: @MarcGravell this isn't about solving my home work, you should see what i already coded in this application. The only thing i was looking for is a way to do this. And the rounding down option is very interesting

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, however when you absolutely have no clue where to start to solve an issue, it's hard to come up with a tentative solution. Perhaps the question doesn't belong on SO however and should be moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to work from the highest coin you have to the lowest.

How many 2s in "giveback"? Take 2* that number off giveback, then calculate how many 1s are left in "giveback". Then how many 0.5s, and so on until the end.

For example:

Giveback = 8.57

4 * 2 euro coins in 8. You can find this by dividing giveback by 2 (4.285) and then rounding down to the nearest whole number (4).

8.57 - (4*2) = 0.57.

0 * 1 euro coins in 0.57

1 * 0.5 coins in 0.57, remaining 0.07

And so on.

I don't want to give you the code, else you can copy/paste in to your assignment, but this logic should help.

Comment: The coding itself shouldn't be a problem it was indeed the logic i was searching for , please don't close this topic just yet. When i get to the coding i'll maybe have some related questions on this topic.

Comment: Would you use an selection or a loop for this?

Comment: You're going to need to keep looping and taking away from the "giveback" variable, until it reaches 0.

Comment: Hi this is what ive already achieved , and by debugging and looking up de the values of my decimals i see it works :
decimal giveback = (alreadyPayed - toPay); 
decimal rest = giveback;
while (rest > 0) 
{
decimal aantal2eur = Math.Floor(rest / 2);
rest = (rest % 2);
decimal aantal1eur = Math.Floor(rest / 1);
rest = (rest % 1);
decimal aantal50cent = Math.Floor(rest / 0.5M);
rest = (rest % 0.5M);
decimal aantal20cent = Math.Floor(rest / 0.2M);
rest = (rest % 0.2M);
..and so on but my problem is how to put this easily in a string without having to use selection with AND operators everytime